# How to convert boolean columns to single property in Entity Framework Core entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In database it's convenient to have multiple bit columns that are either 0 or 1.

For user, in my case, it's easier to pick what options he want's to check in a **checkdown** (dropdown field where you can check multiple options).

I found that I can save an int in database and convert it to enum in my code for easier use, using `HasConversion` function when configuring my entity, like this

```
EntityFrameworkBuilder<MyEntity> builder = ...
builder.Property(x => x.MyEnumId)
    .HasConversion(
        x => x.Value,
        x => MyEnum.FromValue(x));
```

and it works well, in DB it's saved as an int, in my entity I see it as an enum, and I added some translations and sort order for each of those (I don't want to save all that info in database, but offload that work to server).

My goal is to combine multiple boolean fields to a single list of booleans in my entity so that I can then send it to UI in that format so UI can present it as a checkdown, so that in the end I have simple system of making multiple of this checkdown fields in any table/entity I need -> whenever UI sees this list of booleans it automatically converts it to checkdown, and I can easily convert multiple bit columns from DB to a list of booleans in my entity.

How can I convert multiple boolean columns from DB to a single list of booleans in EFCore entity?

Comment: You mean a flagged enum? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum ?

Comment: That looks nice. I didn't know about flagged enums before.  I'd say I'm unsure if this would fit my needs as flagged enums are new to me so currently I don't see how 1,2,4,8,16,32... ids would be 'bad' or 'good' for my software. I'm also saying I'm open for this type of solution

Comment: "In database it's convenient to have multiple bit columns that are either 0 or 1." is it? If not all options can be represented then probably a single `enum` or `tinyint` column is better.

Comment: As long as you store your enum as an int a flagged enum is exactly what you describe you need - as @Charlieface also implied a single enum is probably a better option than using multiple bool columns. However I can make an answer that fits your needs it's most likely a verbatim copy paste of the answers in the linked article. I'd say read the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c and use as solution

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it with flagged enum and come back if it works or doesn't to share the result